# Using tramp in python shell from Cygwin emacs24.5

Tags: python-2.7, emacs, tramp

I like emacs and want to run a python shell by tramp. My emacs24.5 installed in Cygwin64 in a win7 and remote python27 is installed by anaconda2 on another PC with CnetOS 7. My emacs config file about python likes:

```
(provide 'setup-python)
(require 'python-mode)

(setq python-shell-virtualenv-path "/ssh:username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/username/anaconda2/")
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'anaconda-mode)
```

First, I should run `C-x C-f /ssh:username@ip:` to input password and open a remote file through Tramp. Then run `M-x python` to open a python shell remotely. However, there are some thing wrong responsed by remote python like:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/tmp/py-shell-completion-setup-code.py'
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/tmp/py-ffap-setup-code.py'
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/tmp/py-eldoc-setup-code.py'
>>>
```

Please tell me why and how to solve it？

By the way, if I run `M-x ipython` for opening an ipython shell, there is an error like:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
 : cannot connect to X server
```

I do not know why it says `cannot connect to X server`.

Answer (score 0):

Setup of shipped python.el and python-mode.el is not the same. AFAIK M-x (i)python RET would work only with python-mode.el - which is available from melpa. It should work right out of the box, at least that's the goal.

If not, please consider reporting a bug this way: from directory where python-mode.el resides: emacs -Q python-mode.el RET evaluate... Please report any issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode or https://gitlab.com/groups/python-mode-devs/issues

WRT python.el see hints how to customize at head of file.

Comment: It means this is a bug in python-mode.el?

Comment: @nannanmath Not yet. Your setup looks strange. Hunting the errors would require more info, not suitable for a simple Q/A site like this.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the value of variable `py-temp-directory` teaches python-mode where the temporary files are created and searched. The default value of it is `/usr/tmp`, so the temporary files will be created on the local host every time. I set `py-temp-directory` as a remote path by `setq` as `/ssh:username@ip:/usr/tmp` and run `M-x python`. I see that some temporary files are created on remote /usr/tmp. Then, due to search path is also `py-temp-directory`, I reset it as `/usr/tmp`. Run `M-x python`, every thing is OK.

I also try to set `py-custom-temp-directory` as remote path, but it doesn't work. I want to know how to use `py-custom-temp-directory`?